# Flutter Android, Can't copy files to my app's directory on Flutter after using moveToSharedStorage

Tags: android, flutter, download

I've implemented Downloads in my app, using **background_downloader: ^7.11.0**
Everything downloads well, and when the download completes, I want to move the file to my App's directory. I use this package to get my app's current directory: **path_provider**

```
final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

when the download completes, I use this method to move the downloaded file to my "sharedStorage" location as the documentation mentions.

```
final newFilepath = await _fileDownloader.moveToSharedStorage(
    dTask, SharedStorage.downloads);
```

The problem is that, this location isn't appropriate its value is: **/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.pdf**, and I want to move the file to my app's real storage location gotten from path_provider as shown above its value is:

```
/data/user/0/com.mymobileapp/code_cache/pdfFolder/
```

When I move the file using dart, I get this error:
**Cannot rename file to '/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.pdf'**
I tried everything I could find on the internet and CHatGPT,
NOTE: I can't ask read/write storage permissions on Android 13, so I really don't know what to do here. Please can someone help ?

Comment: First try to copy the file. After that remove.